# move \footnoterule to right

Tags: positioning, footnotes, rules

I would like to move a `\footnoterule` to right by 3 cm to be aligned with a footgroup moved to right by 3 cm.

I know that footnote rule uses a `\hrule` To move the rule, I should put it in a `\vbox`, and move it with `\moveleft` or `\moveright`.

But when I did it, I lost kerning. I could include the footgroup in the `\vbox` but it will be very complex.

Any idea?

See the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\leftskip=2cm
\footnotesize \moveleft-2cm\vbox{\footnoterule}
\footnote{A good vertical distance} A bad vertical distance

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: The footnote rule is added during shipout. Using `\moveright` in the document makes no sense for this.

Comment: maybe, but I need to shift it ;-)

Comment: The design is that footnotes are aligned with main texts. Hence you may shift it by adjusting margins ... and then do another dirty trick to protect your main texts. Up to you :P

Comment: yes, for the second part, I can do it. Indeed, the problem is that main text is not left aligned (eledpar columns)

Comment: 2am now... sorry I had never heard about eledmac and its footnote-commands look insane...

Comment: yes, it quite insane, because for complexe case...

Comment: but that is my problem, as maintener, I know how it's work. I can move the block of notes, but not the hrule. That is my question. not more

Comment: If you're in vertical mode, then `\moveright2cm\vbox{\hrule width .4\columnwidth}` is what you want. I don't understand what you mean by “losing kerning”: just add `\kern-3pt` before the moved `\vbox` and `\kern-2.6pt` after it.

Comment: no @egreg, there is a problem of vertical distance between the hrule and the following text.

Comment: Compare the distance between rule and s in `\moveright2cm\vbox{\hrule width .4\columnwidth}
\leftskip=2cm` s and in `\hrule width .4\columnwidth
\leftskip=2cm s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in vertical mode, then

```
\moveright2cm\vbox{\hrule .4\columnwidth}\nointerlineskip
```

will do.

Here's a Plain TeX simulation.

```
\leftskip=2cm

\moveright2cm\vbox{\hrule width 5cm}\nointerlineskip
s

\bigskip

\hrule width 5cm
s

\bye
```

[image]

Of course you'll have a strut after the rule and also some kerning (-3pt before and 2.6pt after the rule is what LaTeX uses for `\footnoterule`).

```
\leftskip=2cm

\kern-3pt
\moveright2cm\vbox{\hrule width 5cm}\nointerlineskip
\kern2.6pt
\strut s

\bigskip

\kern-3pt
\hrule width 5cm
\kern2.6pt
\strut s

\bye
```

[image]

The same result is obtained if

```
\moveright2cm\vbox{
  \kern-3pt
  \hrule width 5cm
  \kern2.6pt
}\nointerlineskip
```

is used for moving the rule to the right.

Comment: thanks, but for some other technical reason, I prefer to keep the \footnoterule as one single block. cf my own answer.

Comment: @Maïeul I'm not sure of what you mean.

Comment: in your example \footnoterule is split as : kern + vbox containing hrule + kern. I need to have : vbox containing kern + hrule + kern.

Comment: @Maïeul Put the kerns in the box; it's as simple as that.

Comment: yes,but in your example, the \strut add a spurious vertical space that I don't want.

Comment: @Maïeul I don't understand what you're saying: if you don't want the strut, just remove it! I used it just to emulate what the usual footnote mechanism does and it belongs to the paragraph with the “s”, not to the rule.

Comment: I have forgottent to paste the \nointerlineskip, which is, indeed, what prevent spurious space.

Comment: compare `\moveright 2cm\vbox{\footnoterule}\nointerlineskip xxx` and `\moveright 2cm\vbox{\footnoterule} xxx`. Thank a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

When I look into the process generating footnotes, I found that `LaTeX` is doing everything in vertical mode. Therefore it is really difficult to find somewhere to insert a horizontal space. Finally I can only share this dirty trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{17cm}
    \noindent text before \footnote{A good vertical distance} text after
\clearpage
\vspace*{17cm}
    \makeatletter
    \let\oldfootnoterule=\footnoterule
    \def\footnoterule{\moveright3cm\vbox{\oldfootnoterule}}
    \def\@makefntext#1{\parindent 1em\noindent \hskip3cm \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss \@makefnmark }#1}
    \noindent text before \footnote{A good vertical distance} text after
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: that is, indeed, very dirty. I will look at it to show if adaptable/usable for eledmac...

Answer (score 0):

One french people TeXuser send me a good solution. We have to:

- put the rule in a vbox
- put this vbox in a hbox, with a kern inside the hbox
- be certain than this hbox is followed by a \vbox AND NOT by a \hbox.

See the three followings example

```
\newbox\a
\leftskip=2cm
\setbox\a=\vbox{x}
\footnoterule
\unvbox\a
% normal position position 

\newpage

\setbox\a=\hbox{x}
\hbox{\kern 2cm\vbox{\footnoterule}}
\unhbox\a
% good x position, bad y position

\newpage

\setbox\a=\vbox{x}
\hbox{\kern 2cm\vbox{\footnoterule}}
\unvbox\a
```