# Drawing footnote separator line

Tags: footnotes, rules

Footnotes have a horizontal line above them, separating them from the body text on the page. How can I draw this line in a different context? I also would like the to vary the length of the line.

Comment: To vary the length for footnotes you can modify \footnoterule.  For some other context, you will probably need to create a new float type.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198150/move-footnoterule-to-right

Comment: Check out \rule

Comment: Do you mean this command: `\rule[lift]{width}{height}`?

Comment: @jon I want the placement on the page to be the same place as the line for the footnote separator.

Comment: What is the "different context" then?  This question might make more sense with a diagram or two that shows the contexts....