# Right align footnote section rule

Tags: xetex, footnotes, polyglossia, arabic

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{xecolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\definergbcolor{titlecolor}{750000}

\setmainlanguage{arabic}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Scale=2.0,Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits,Numbers=Proportional]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\titlefont[Scale=2.0,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\begin{document}

    \section{الفصل الأول: المقدمة}
    نحمده حمداً كثيراً، والصلاة والسلام على نبيه الذي أرسله بالحق بشيراً ونذيراً، هاديًا داعيًا إليه بإذنه وسراجًا منيراً، وعلى آله وصحبه الذين ساروا في نصرة دينه سيرا حثيثًا وبعد:\\[12pt]
    فيقول العاجز الحقير الفقير إلى ربه المستجير، أبو عبد الكبير محمد الشهير بعبد الجليل السامرودي -تسامح الله وتجاوز عن جرائمه، وجرائم شيخه الجلية والخفية-: الاختلاف في أئمتنا أهل الحديث خاصة في إتمام البسملة والاكتفاء على لفظ بسم الله فقط في أوائل الأكل والأشربة والتوضيء وغيرها حتى جرى بينهم الاشتهارات ووقع العوام في بحار التردد، والريب والارتياب، بل ضاقت عليهم المسألة بما رحبت. فأردت أن أنقح لك المسألة في جزء بدلائل السنة السنية الصحيحة الصريحة ليتميز بها الحق النجيح والباطل القبيح. وتبصرة لكل رجل بصير سميته: بـ «الغمغمة في سنية التسمية عند الأطعمة وغيرها دون البسملة». أسأل الله سبحانه وتعالى أن يوفقني على الإتمام، وهو المستعان وعليه التكلان.\\[12pt]
    أقول وبالله أصول وأجول: عليكم -يامعشر أهل العلم خاصة- أن تتيقظوا من مغامات الغفلة، واعلموا أن الله سبحانه وتعالى ما افترض على أحد من عباده إلا الطاعة له ولرسوله، وجعل الذل والصغار على من خالفهما، وجعل الفوز والنجاح لمن اتبع أمرهما ، كما قال عز شأنه:\textxecolor{titlecolor}{﴿وَمَنْ يُطِعِ اللهَ وَرَسُولَهُ فَقَدْ فَازَ فَوْزًا عَظِيمًا﴾}\footnote{سورة الأحزاب (آية رقم:71).}.وحذر الناس كل الحذر ممن خالف أمرهما فقال سبحانه عز شأنه: \textxecolor{titlecolor}{﴿فَلْيَحْذَرِ الَّذِينَ يُخَالِفُونَ عَنْ أَمْرِهِ أَنْ تُصِيبَهُمْ فِتْنَةٌ أَوْ يُصِيبَهُمْ عَذَابٌ أَلِيمٌ﴾}\footnote{سورة النور (آية رقم: 63).}

\end{document}
```

And here is how it looks:
[image: Visual Output]

I need to move the footnote section rule (highlighted red in the picture) to the right to match the document language. I've tried `\rightfootnoterule` but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: See here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198150/move-footnoterule-to-right

Comment: I was hoping not doing anything manually since I'm already using `polyglossia` and`XeLaTeX`, and have set the main language to Arabic. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\footnoterule` should occupy no vertical space. Here's a redefinition that places it at the right margin:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xecolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\definergbcolor{titlecolor}{750000}

\setmainlanguage{arabic}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Scale=2.0,Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits,Numbers=Proportional]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\titlefont[Scale=2.0,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
  \kern-3pt
  \nointerlineskip
  \moveright.6\columnwidth\vbox{\hrule width.4\columnwidth}%
  \nointerlineskip
  \kern2.6pt
}

\begin{document}

    \section{الفصل الأول: المقدمة}
    نحمده حمداً كثيراً، والصلاة والسلام على نبيه الذي أرسله بالحق بشيراً ونذيراً، هاديًا داعيًا إليه بإذنه وسراجًا منيراً، وعلى آله وصحبه الذين ساروا في نصرة دينه سيرا حثيثًا وبعد:\\[12pt]
    فيقول العاجز الحقير الفقير إلى ربه المستجير، أبو عبد الكبير محمد الشهير بعبد الجليل السامرودي -تسامح الله وتجاوز عن جرائمه، وجرائم شيخه الجلية والخفية-: الاختلاف في أئمتنا أهل الحديث خاصة في إتمام البسملة والاكتفاء على لفظ بسم الله فقط في أوائل الأكل والأشربة والتوضيء وغيرها حتى جرى بينهم الاشتهارات ووقع العوام في بحار التردد، والريب والارتياب، بل ضاقت عليهم المسألة بما رحبت. فأردت أن أنقح لك المسألة في جزء بدلائل السنة السنية الصحيحة الصريحة ليتميز بها الحق النجيح والباطل القبيح. وتبصرة لكل رجل بصير سميته: بـ «الغمغمة في سنية التسمية عند الأطعمة وغيرها دون البسملة». أسأل الله سبحانه وتعالى أن يوفقني على الإتمام، وهو المستعان وعليه التكلان.\\[12pt]
    أقول وبالله أصول وأجول: عليكم -يامعشر أهل العلم خاصة- أن تتيقظوا من مغامات الغفلة، واعلموا أن الله سبحانه وتعالى ما افترض على أحد من عباده إلا الطاعة له ولرسوله، وجعل الذل والصغار على من خالفهما، وجعل الفوز والنجاح لمن اتبع أمرهما ، كما قال عز شأنه:\textxecolor{titlecolor}{﴿وَمَنْ يُطِعِ اللهَ وَرَسُولَهُ فَقَدْ فَازَ فَوْزًا عَظِيمًا﴾}\footnote{سورة الأحزاب (آية رقم:71).}.وحذر الناس كل الحذر ممن خالف أمرهما فقال سبحانه عز شأنه: \textxecolor{titlecolor}{﴿فَلْيَحْذَرِ الَّذِينَ يُخَالِفُونَ عَنْ أَمْرِهِ أَنْ تُصِيبَهُمْ فِتْنَةٌ أَوْ يُصِيبَهُمْ عَذَابٌ أَلِيمٌ﴾}\footnote{سورة النور (آية رقم: 63).}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, note that `a4wide` has been deprecated for about 15 years. If you want to modify the page setup, use the `geometry` package.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (for right-to-left typing), in your preamble (of course the length is adjustable):

```
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\rule{0.4\linewidth}{0.4pt}\hfill}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I've pasted this line right after `\definergbcolor{titlecolor}{750000}` in the `MWE`. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Iforgot the typing was right-to-left on inserting the footnote rule. See my updated answer. Btw, `a4wide` is obsolete. Use the `geometry` package to change the margins.